# Inserting selected items from a ListBox into MSSQL database with ADO.NET (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listbox, ado.net

I would like to know how to insert selected items from a ListBox into a MSSQL Database.

I am developing an ASP.NET web app and this is the problem:

1. I have a Listbox named `lbxRuoli` and items are loaded directly from the database:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select descrizione_Ruoli, id_Ruoli from Ruoli", conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ListItem li = new ListItem("- SELEZIONA -", "");
lbxRuoli.Items.Add(li);
while (dr.Read())
{
    li = new ListItem(dr["descrizione_Ruoli"].ToString(), dr["id_Ruoli"].ToString());
    lbxRuoli.Items.Add(li);
}
dr.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
```

2. Now it comes to write the `INSERT` for the selected items:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < lbxRuoli.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lbxRuoli.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Utenti.Ruoli] (id_Utenti, id_Ruoli) values(@id, @idR)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idR", lbxRuoli.SelectedValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

It happens that I only insert **the same first selected item** for the total numbers of the selected items.

It would be wonderful if someone can help me!
Thanks to every one in advance!

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: `lbxRuoli.SelectedValue` is only the current, first item.  Notice how it ignores the `i` index.

Comment: Thanks LarsTech for you answer! I already added the [i] to lbxRuoli.SelectedValue as you suggest but I got an error I do not remember at the moment. Am going to let you know soon! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Connections need to be not only closed but disposed to release unmanaged objects. `using` blocks handle this even if there is an error.
Commands also need to be disposed. To accomplish this they should be declared local to the method where they are used. `using` blocks will close and dispose you database objects.

You don't want to hold a connection open while you update the user interface. Fill a `DataTable`, close the connection (the `using` block does it) and then fill the `ListBox` from the `DataTable`.

To insert the data create the connection, command and fill the parameters collection outside the loop. Only the values of the parameters change inside the loop

The code below demonstrates how to use the `.Add` method for parameters. I had to guess at the type and size of the parameters. Check your database and adjust the code accordingly making sure that the parameter values are compatible with the `SqlDbType`.

```
    private string ConStr = "Your connection string";
    private DataTable GetListData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select descrizione_Ruoli, id_Ruoli from Ruoli", cn))
        {
            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private void FillListBox()
    {
        DataTable dt = GetListData();
        ListItem li = new ListItem("- SELEZIONA -", "");
        lbxRuoli.Items.Add(li);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            li = new ListItem(row["descrizione_Ruoli"].ToString(), row["id_Ruoli"].ToString());
            lbxRuoli.Items.Add(li);
        }

    }
    private void InsertData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Utenti.Ruoli] (id_Utenti, id_Ruoli) values(@id, @idR)", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idR", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            cn.Open();
            foreach (ListItem li in lbxRuoli.Items)
            { 
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = li.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["idR"].Value = li.Value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mary, thank you so much for your aid. I used the USING for CONNECTION and COMMANDS but I began to avoid it preferring closing them manually (this is an extract of the code). Thanks for the suggestion about using .Add instead of .AddWithValue. I will let you know soon about your code. Thanks again for your precious tips!!!

Comment: If you want to do it manually you need to also call .Dispose on both connections and commands. They may be using unmanaged resources that are release in their .Dispose methods. You will need a try...catch...finally to put the code in the finally so you will be sure it runs. Unless you can correct the error in the catch it is better to let it bubble up to the calling code and inform the user in the UI code.